# Show all tags related to a category?

Tags: categories, relations, tags

Is it possible to show all tags that are related to a category? I can't find anything on it.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

*What I am looking for is this:*

I know a category slug or name. I want to get all tags associated with entries in that category.

I can't seem to get this to work using the relatedTo param.

Comment: Is your tag custom field inside the category or an entry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the relatedTo param on `craft.tags` like you can with any Element inside Craft.

All Elements inside Craft can be related to one another. There is a `.relatedTo` [parameter](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.tags#relatedTo) available on all of the query elements like `craft.entries` and `craft.tags`.

You will need to pass a category object into this relatedTo parameter. I have included the group param below but this can be omitted if you want to query all of your tags.

`{% set tags = craft.tags.group( 'groupName' ).relatedTo( category ) %}`

More info on using Relations in Craft: https://craftcms.com/docs/relations

---

**UPDATE**

The `relatedTo` param takes one of the following:

- An AssetFileModel, CategoryModel, EntryModel, UserModel, or TagModel
  object
- An element’s ID
- An array of element objects and/or IDs

To get a CategoryModel using a slug inside your template you can use:

`{% set category = craft.categories.slug( 'theslug' ).first() %}`

This will set `category` to a CategoryModel which you can then use inside the `.relatedTo` param in the above example.

---

**UPDATE 2**

If you've set category to have their own URL's then `category` inside the template you've set to use is a CategoryModel.

You then set `entries` to all entries related to the category. Finally, use these entries to get all related tags.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo( category ).find() %}
{% set tags = craft.tags.relatedTo( entries ).find() %}
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I set the actual category?

Comment: That depends on where you are setting these tags to be displayed. You can get categories the same way you get entries using `craft.categories`. If you have set categories to have their own URLs then `category` will be the current category you're viewing.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help! I just started using Craft, so I'm still trying to wrap my ahead around some of the concepts.

Comment: Ok, I updated my original question with an edit. I'm still not getting this to work, and maybe I was misunderstood.

Comment: So I tried to do that and nothing displayed. I used `{% set category = craft.categories.slug('slug') %}` and `{% set tags = craft.tags.relatedTo( category ) %}`. I guess I will just mess around with it a bit more.

Comment: You need to use `.first()` when getting the category. Are you setting these tags on a category?

Comment: Here is how I am trying to use this. This will be on a category page. So, I will know what category it is. From there, I will list all the entries in the category. At the bottom, I want a tag cloud type thing to showcase all the tags related to this category used in the entries listed above it. Does that make sense?

Comment: So your tags are set on the entries? This means you need to use the entries to get the related tags and these entries will all be from one category.

Comment: Kick ass, update 2 was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!