# How do I pull categories from another category group for members of another category?

Tags: templating

`I will try this again.

I have an index page for each category within category group 1 (`markets`).

I loop through the descendants of the given category to create filter buttons.

How do i pull all the categories from a 2nd category group (`country`) assigned to each `market` from `markets`  - listing them only once

For the `market` from category group-1 (`markets`), I am using:

`{% set segments = craft.categories.descendantOf(category) %}`
`{% for category in segments %}`
``` button html using {{ category.title }}
``{% endfor %} ```

For the `countries` from category group-2 (`country`), I tried using:

`{% set name = craft.categories.group('country').relatedTo(category) %}`
`{% for nation in name %}` `button html with {{ nation.countryName }}`
`{% endear %}`

Where `countryName` is the field name for the `country` group.

I did not get a template error.  But nothing printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot about the related entries.  So, I actually want to pull the related `countries` from the `**entries**` related to the `market`.

Here is the solution.  [The key was the answer to this related question about related tags.](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15257/show-all-tags-related-to-a-category)

`{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(category).find() %}`
`{% set nation = craft.categories.group('country').relatedTo(entries).find()%}`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
{% set name = craft.categories.group('country').relatedTo(category) %}
```

to

```
{% set name = craft.categories.group('country').relatedTo(category.slug) %}
```

Use the slug parameter to target a specific category in the category group. More parameters can be found here: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.categories

```
{% set category = craft.categories
    .group('nameOfCategoryGroup')
    .slug('specificCategoryInGroup')
    .limit(1)
    .first()
%}
```

Comment: I am still very much a novice.  I literally tried it with (category.slug) and then with (category.market).   I got nothing - no errors and no buttons.

Comment: Is the category an actual category object? I updated my answer that shows you how to get a category by its slug.

Comment: I am not trying to pull a category. I want to pull related categories from a second category group

I have 2 `category groups`   Group 1 = `markets`  Group 2 = `countries`.

I have an entry index for each `market` that appears in `markets` (`Group 1`).  I then loop through each `descendant` of a given `market` to create filter buttons.


Next, I want to pull the related `Group 2` `countries` associated with the given `Group 1` `market' -- 1 to many.  

So, looking across all the entries in the index associated with the `Group 1` `market` what `countries` from `Group 2` are related.